# Running Python from Command Line

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I wrote a very simple python program in hope that I could run it from the Windows command line. In the terminal I type python.exe hw.py and instead of running the program I get the python interpreter. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Program:

```
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello()
```

I've also tried even simpler programs such as

```
print("Hello world!")
```

and

```
return "Hello World!"
```

but nothing works. The goal here is to get output in the console. Thanks!

Comment: Are you typing it as `python.exe hw.py`? Or `python.exe \n hw.py`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html - for reference.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable this is what you need, just run as `my_script.py`

Comment: @MorganThrapp It's all on the same line no "\n"

Comment: If you have python in your PATH in windows you should just be able to type `python path/to/your/file/hw.py`

Comment: @Avantol13 that stops the interpreter from coming up but i am still not seeing any output from my program

Comment: That's because you're not printing anything out. You need to use print instead of raise

Comment: Yes, thank you. You have no idea how long I've been trying to get that to work

Comment: Whoops, I meant return. Not raise

Comment: @Ivar Eriksson No problem! I've had my fair share of staring at something for way too long. Sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize my comments as an answer, to call the file from the command line you need the location to your python installation in your PATH variable in Windows. Then you can just use the following in the command line:

`python path/to/file/filename.py`

If you're trying to print to the console you need to use `print("Hello!")` and not `return`.

Comment: If the system is configured correctly, just run `path/to/file/filename.py`. Managing `PATH` for multiple Python installations is a pain (except with virtual environments). With Python 3 installed, .py scripts should be associated with py.exe, which lets you use virtual Unix shebangs such as `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python3`, or explicit Windows paths in the shebang such as `#!C:\Python27\python.exe`. Just set a common scripts directory in `PATH`.